# Auto-complete CSS property names for rule sets on Firebug?

Tags: css, properties, firebug

On Firebug, when inspecting an element, is there a way to Auto-complete CSS property names for rule sets similarly to ctr+alt+space in some IDE for other languages?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Please post an example, where would you type ctrl+space?

Comment: Many CSS editors will auto complete when you're inside of a rule and give you options like `background-image, border` if you've typed 'b'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. But you can double click inside the class rules and start typing a CSS property name - Firebug will give you suggestions/autocompletion